# How can i record my digital piano's sound on PC?

Tags: music, vst, cubase, fl-studio, piano

I have a roland rp-302 digital piano.I love it's sound the problem is that i have gone sick of the VSTS such as addictive keys,ivory etc. and want to use the real sound of the digital piano itself in my tracks and videos.How can i record it? i am able to connect it my PC speakers and get output but it isn't recording in audacity or any other similar program?

Answer (score 1):

If you simply want to record the piano with Audacity, you will need a **stereo line input** on the computer. You connect the `OUTPUT` stereo phone jack(⅛ inch I think) from the RP-302 to the line input on the computer using a suitable stereo cable.

If your computer doesn't have a line input, you would need to buy an audio interface with the relevant inputs. A dedicated audio interface will always give you better signal quality than using the computer's internal sound circuitry. If you do this regularly, you should think about getting a dedicated audio interface either way.

Note: Using the computer's built-in sound inputs will add a lot of latency(delay) to the signal. This shouldn't really matter for a solo piano, unless you need to monitor(listen to) the piano through the computer while recording. But hopefully, the piano will continue to output the sound itself while connected to the computer.

If you are having problems accessing the input from Audacity or any other audio software, try installing an ASIO driver like [ASIO4ALL](http://tippach.business.t-online.de/asio4all/index.html). This driver will also lower the latency and give you access to some other useful settings.

> Useful links
>   [Audacity FAQ:Recording - How To's](http://manual.audacityteam.org/man/faq_recording_how_to_s.html)
>   [SOS - Choosing An Audio Interface](https://www.soundonsound.com/sound-advice/choosing-audio-interface)
>   [Questions - Computer Line Input](https://sound.stackexchange.com/search?q=computer+line+input)
>   [Questions - Audio Interface](https://sound.stackexchange.com/search?q=audio+interface)
>   [ASIO4ALL info](http://tippach.business.t-online.de/asio4all/intro.html)

if you have any questions, use the comments below.